# Calling python function from another file

Tags: python, function, reference

I am trying to reference a variable from one python file to another.

I have a base file that has a variable value, `current_time` and I want to call this variable in another python function that is in another python file.

This is what I tried doing:

From the file I am trying to call the variable:

```
ref_path = os.path.split(os.getcwd())[0]
ref_path = os.path.join(ref_path, "folder_1", "folder_2", "folder_3")
```

Now that I am pointing to the destination folder when I try doing

```
from ref_path import function as function
```

I am getting an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ref_path'`

I am trying to call `function.current_time`

Comment: is another file is in different folder and not a part of your project? if yes, i suggest you to make that file a part of your project

Answer (score 1):

Add the path to base file in your `syspath` and import the variable.

```py
import sys
sys.path.append(ref_path)

from function import *
# Now you can use the variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you import the file?

assuming the ref path is the directory next to this file you could try this:

```
import os

fullPath = os.path.realpath(__file__)  #this file
thisDir = os.path.dirname(fullPath) # this files directory

from ref_file import ref_module 

print(ref_module.GetCurrentTime())
```